# Is there any significance to complex function "monotone in norm?"

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

So, I was reading a question earlier where someone asked if something would be strictly monotone in the complex plane, and the comment was that this would be meaningless, since the complex numbers aren't an ordered field.

What came to mind was a concept in my head of "monotone in norm".   This would be something of the sort $\forall x,y\in \mathbb C,\|x\|<\|y\|\implies \|f(x)\|<\|f(y)\|$.

Is this a meaningful property for complex functions?  My complex analysis is...pretty sparse, alas.

Comment: In the converse sense, there are several interesting *analytic* functions for which this is true. For example, all polynomials are eventually monotone in norm.
$$\left.\right.$$
This is probably pedantism, but if you didn't mean to restrict your focus to analytic functions, functions of ``monotone norm'' aren't in themselves very interesting or restrictive. They could do anything. For instance, take a natural log function that is nowhere continuous (which you can construct using two or more branches). This isn't a very nice or interesting function, but it has your property.

Comment: (nonconstant polynomials..)

Comment: @enthdegree No, polynomials other than $z^n$ are not monotone in norm. Also, why so much whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only holomorphic functions that have this property are monomials $cz^n$. Indeed, the property implies (by continuity) that $|x|\le |y|\implies |f(x)|\le |f(y)|$, which in turn yields $|x|=|y|\implies |f(x)|=|f(y)|$. So, for every unimodular constant $\zeta $ the function $f(\zeta z)/f(z)$ has constant modulus, hence is constant. So,  $f(\zeta z)\equiv c(\zeta) f(z)$ from where, comparing the Taylor coefficients, we can conclude that at most one term of the Taylor series can be nonzero.

If we consider non-holomorphic functions, then it's more natural to look at real-valued functions. For them, the property you described is known as being a "radial[ly] increasing function". They are sometimes used for [radial basis function](http://www.anc.ed.ac.uk/rbf/intro/node7.html) approximation. However, they are not nearly as common as their *decreasing* counterparts, which are used all the time as [mollifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) (and also for [RBF approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function)).